# Getting 1000+ reads with a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I properly call a function in a useEffect? Only want to call the function on page load.

I've got multiple functions that are being called in a use effect but the way it's set up I'm getting 1000+ reads and maxing out my quota instantly.

```
const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
const [myDisplayName, setMyDisplayName] = useState("");
const [projectList, setProjectList] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
      if(!user) navigate("/login")
      fetchUserName();
      fetchTotalProjects();
    },[])

const fetchUserName = async () => {
    try {
      const query = await db
        .collection("user")
        .where("uid", "==", user?.uid)
        .get();
      const data = await query.docs[0].data();
      setMyDisplayName(data.firstName);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

const fetchTotalProjects = async () => {
    try {
      const query = await db
        .collection("projects")
        .where("uid", "==", user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          const tempData = [];
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data();
            tempData.push(data);
          });
          setProjectList(tempData);
        });
      const data = await query.docs[0].data();
      setProjectList(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You're using the useEffect properly. The issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Getting the UID from Firebase was coming back undefined the first 3 -5 times and then it would get it, meaning the useEffect would fire until the data was retrieved.

Solution: Get your user uid from Firebase like this

```
const user = auth?.currentUser;
```